# Economic questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is it me, or am I not able to find any question board regarding economics?
My point is, that it would be great with a board were people could ask questions about economics in general, world economics and so on.

"Why is Greece close to a national bankruptcy", 
"What's the difference between MasterCard and VISA" 
And so on!

Comment: Support the proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42351/economics or if you're into finance economics: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41407/finance-economics

Comment: "Whats the difference between MasterCard and VISA" would be unlikely to be on topic for an Economics site.

Comment: Im a Private Banker myself, and enjoy economics in general. Regarding the MasterCard and VISA ex., would be an in-direct question regarding economics.

Comment: While these are just examples, we understand, you'd need to be far more detailed in your question - what you actually want to know, what differences are relevant (one is made of plastic, the other is made of unicorns), what factors you'd like people to theorise on about why Greece is almost kaput, et c. =)

Comment: Short examples of my point regarding economics. But I see what you meen J. Steen. :)

Comment: [economics](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) and [economy](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy) tags at _Politics.SE_ look quite lively...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proposals for new topical Stack Exchange QnA sites are handled via a site called Area 51. I see there is [a proposal for an Economics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42351/economics) site active there. You can read some about the process and how you can be involved on the Area 51 [FAQ page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Not every subject area is a good candidate for SE style QnA. Of the ones that are, often only a subset of issues related to the field make good questions. Of your two proposed questions, I suggest one of them is good and one of them would probably not fly even on a site dedicated to Economics. Perhaps it would work on a [Personal Finance](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money) site, but it is kind of a dodgy question.

In order to launch a site, example questions have to be approved that demonstrate the topic could fit under the kind of QnA that SE sites focus on, and several hundred people need to commit to helping get it off the ground.

Comment: Hi Caleb. Thank you for your answer, and a thanks to Bart. I am going to support the Economic topic on Area 51! :)